# wp_enqueue_scripts not loading js files

Tags: wordpress

I'm using wp_enqueue rather than including in the footer directly. I found that the path for the js files is correct (checked via page source).

**NOT WORKING**

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/vendor/jquery.js', array (), NULL, true);

wp_enqueue_script( 'input', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/vendor/what-input.js', array ('jquery'), NULL, true);

wp_enqueue_script( 'foundation-core', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/vendor/foundation.js', array ('jquery'), NULL, true);

wp_enqueue_script( 'ext', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/app.js', array ('jquery'), NULL, true);
```

**WORKING**

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>  
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: You forgot the add_action.. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: the issue above solved by adding jQuery instead of $ like said here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536160/wp-enqueue-script-not-working..  can someone explain why.

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function($) and then you can use the shortcut $ in the function.

Answer (score 1):

In Wordpress to enqueue style and Css you wp_enqueue_script method. 
That you wrote fine but you have to run these function at the time when WordPress enqueue scripts.
i.e you have to call these function at `wp_enqueue_scripts` action. 
`wp_enqueue_scripts` this action will call when WordPress load scripts.
so your code will look like

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_site_scripts' );
function load_my_site_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/vendor/jquery.js', array (), NULL, true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'input', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/vendor/what-input.js', array ('jquery'), NULL, true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'foundation-core', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/vendor/foundation.js', array ('jquery'), NULL, true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ext', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/app.js', array ('jquery'), NULL, true);
}
```

Add this code in your theme functions.php

Comment: Yes you need to add this into this action only.

Answer (score 0):

Try with creating function

```
function load_css_js() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'gdgt-base', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/gdgt-base.css', false, NULL, 'all' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'gdgt-icon', get_template_directory_uri() . '/icons/css/gdgt.css', false, NULL, 'all' );

wp_register_script( 'gdgt-base', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/gdgt-base.js', array( 'jquery' ), NULL, false );
wp_enqueue_script( 'gdgt-base' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_css_js' );
```